# When finding residues, is there a way/approach that simplifies the computations below?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have $f(z)=\frac{z^{2}}{1+z^{4}}$, which has poles the fourth roots of $-1$: $$
 a_{n} = \exp \biggl(i\biggl[ \frac{\pi}{4}+(n-1)\frac{\pi}{2} \biggr]   \biggr), \quad n=1,2,3,4,
$$   and I want to compute $\mathrm{Res}(f; a_1)=\lim_{z\to a_1} \frac{a_1^{2}}{(a_1-a_2)(a_1-a_3)(a_1-a_4)}$.

How can I find the residue without doing a lot of tedious computations?

My approach has been to use Euler's formula but the computations that I do end up being very tedious and time consuming. I want to be able to do these computations in an exam setting (without calculators). How do the experts approach this? Can someone show me their detailed computations, please?

I skipped doing alot of these before but now that I have to do a lot of them to find resides, I wish I could learn some technique that would simplify my life a little.

The answer, by the way, is  $\mathrm{Res}(f, a_1)=\frac{1}{4}\exp\biggl( -\frac{i\pi}{4} \biggr)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is this.

Let $\zeta=z-a_1$.

We want the coefficient of $\zeta^{-1}$ in $\dfrac{(\zeta+a_1)^2}{1+(\zeta+a_1)^4}$,

which is the coefficient of $1$ in
$$
\frac{\zeta(\zeta+a_1)^2}{1+(\zeta+a_1)^4} = \frac{a_1^2\zeta+O(\zeta^2)}{(1+a_1^4)+4a_1^3\zeta+O(\zeta^2)}=\frac{a_1^2+O(\zeta)}{4a_1^3+O(\zeta)},
$$
that is $\dfrac{1}{4a_1}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The quick shortcut is that if $f(z)= \frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$  then at each  simple pole of $f$,  $Res[ f,z_0] =\frac{ g(z)}{h'(z)}$.

In your example this becomes $Res[f]= \frac{ z^2}{ 4 z^3} =\frac{1}{4} z^{-1}$.

PS. This formula works except in unusual cases when $z_0$ is a pole of order two or more.
In such cases you can tell that more work is needed, because the shortcut formula will degenerate to an undefined expression involving  division by zero.  If you ever encounter a double pole you can search online to find the more complicated formula  that covers that case.